# Can you tell me what the difference between low grades and bad grades is?

Tags: grammar

Firstly, excuse my poor English.While I studied Present Perfect Tense, a sentence had on my mind
"I got many bad grades last semester, but I haven't had any low grades so far this term."
So, are low grades worse than bad grades? Otherwise, am I wrong?

Comment: Hello dissonancex!Welcome to EL&U. In the context of your sentence, bad and low can be taken to have a similar meaning. There is no discernable difference. "Low" = "bad", and vice-versa. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the [help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help). Please consider whether your question might be better suited for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Equating _low_ and _bad_ is part of [the `Up/Down` metaphor theme complex](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf). School grades are like company stocks -- higher is better.

Answer (score 1):

[Absolute and relative](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/grammar-language/difference-between-absolute-and-relative/) references.

A **low score** is one that is not great in value, from a numerical perspective. This is independent of any measurement of "quality". E.g.:

> He scored 4 points out of 10, quite *a low score*.

A **bad score** is one that does not compare favorably to another. This is independent of the absolute value of the score. E.g.:

> However, the average was actually 2.5 out of 10, so his score, while low, *is quite good*.

See more: [Low](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/low) (definition 3) | [Bad](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bad) (definition 1)

Comment: This is about grades (marks), not scores.

Comment: Do grades not use an arbitrary scale on which this logic could be mapped?

Comment: Grades (marks) are what you receive in school. Scores are what you get in sports or on tests like SAT tests. The OP said he got bad grades, not a bad score.

Comment: Note that depending on the grading system, a low score might be good or bad. The score might be the number of mistakes you made, the lower, the better.